# Ordering imports - ordered-imports, import from namespace

Tags: typescript, tslint

I cannot rearrange imports that are not provided by syntax
import {} from '';

For example: 
import clock = jasmine.clock; 
Where jasmine is a namespace.

I'm using rules from tslint ordered-imports

```
"groups": [
            {
        "name": "@ourProject",
        "match": "^@ourProject",
        "order": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "relative dir",
        "match":  "^\\.\\.",
        "order": 3
      },
      {
        "name": "relative dir",
        "match": "^\\.",
        "order": 4
      },
      {
        "name": "@3rd party/other not matching",
        "match": ".*",
        "order": 1
      }
    ]
```

I want to add imports like example above (jasmine one) to the first group with other 3rd party imports

I've tried to match them with value of match null, but also in way of "not @ourProject & not relative dir ...." but they still seems to be not rearrangable

I got imports sorted like:

- Group 1: angular, rxjs, other 3rd party
- Group 2: @ourProject
- Group 3: relative directories

and "import clock = jasmine.clock;"  is accepted by any of groups

I want to join import clock = jasmine.clock to Group 1